# how use coroutine to remodel / replace the callback implementation

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Trying to replace the using callback with coroutines.   Having a implementation using callback and not sure what is the right approach if coroutines could help.

This is the implementation with callback. 
It has a class `repository` to provide data from either local database or network remote.

```
    class Repository() {

        var callback = //callback is provided by the caller
        var isReady = false

        var data = null
        var firstimeCall = true  //only need to get from database at first time call

        fun getData(cb: ICallback) {

            callback = cb
            isReady = false

            if (firstimeCall) {
                firstimeCall = false
                data = doGetDataFromDatabase()  //sync call to get data from database
                isReady = true
                callback.onComplete(this)
            }

            isReady = false
            data = doGetDataFromNetwork() {// async call and lamda as the callback
                isReady = true
                saveToDatabase(data)
                callback.onComplete(this)
            }
        }
    }
```

the `repository.getData()` could be called multiple times, only first time it will return the data from database first, then
getting from network and saving, then call callback.onComplete() to return the data.

Any other time, it will only do getting from network/save/return data through the callback.

the use case are:

1. directly using `Repository`, like

```
     repository.getData()  -- 1st time call
     repository.getData()  -- later call it again
```

2. there are multiple `repositories`,  the data from each one will be aggregated into a final data.

for this case there is a `Aggregator`  to hold the `repositories`, and provides `onComplete()` callback to process data if all
`repositories` are ready.

```
    class Aggregator {
        var repos = ArrayList<Repository>()

        fun getData() {

            for (r in repos) {
                Thread {
                    r.getData(callback)
                }.start()
            }
        }

        fun processData(data: ArrayList()) {
            ......
        }

        val callback = object ICallback (onComplete{repo->

            val hasAllComplete = repos.all {
                it.isReady
            }

            if (hasAllComplete) {
                var finalData = ArrayList<Data>()
                for (r in repos) {
                    finalData.add(r.data)
                }

                processData(finalData)
            }

        })
    }
```

so in the case it has two `Repository`,  the `Aggregator.getData()` will get data from the two repositories.
when one `Repository` is complete its `getData()` call, it will callback to the callback's onComplete() where
the `Aggregator` will check wether all `repositories` are ready for data to be processed.

The same callback flow is used for the network call aswell.

Question:

In this case how to change to use coroutines, so that only after getting data from the database are complete for both `repositories`,
then it will start to get data from the network,  without using callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's relevant anymore, but you could have a look at [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html).

More info here:
https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf#1aaf

I have a similar problem, and I think this might be the solution to it.

Make sure you also read more about Flow and its usage before actually using it, since there are some caveats with handling exceptions (exception transparency), etc.